# Displaying a Mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, echo

Wordpress 4.2.2

I've got the connection to my database working just fine. Now I just want to print or echo a table from my database using this php code and display it on my webpage.

I can't get it to display anything and I think it's because of the echo statement. I never inserted anything in the echo thinking that it doesn't require anything. I think the echo string is printing out $row which fetches $result which has my query in it.

I've tried making a separate echo and print statement with no results.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

```
$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM    DUAL");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
```

***EDIT:*** above is the code I copied from php.net. Below is my version.

```
$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "f2f3243f2");
mysql_select_db("my_DB"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fakeDB"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
```

***EDIT:*** Thank you @andrewsi. `var_dump($row)` has displayed the information I wanted.

> array(5) { ["CharName"]=> string(6) "Majaba" ["Level"]=> string(1) "3" ["class"]=> string(4) "Bard" ["race"]=> string(8) "High Elf" ["skills"]=> string(8) "Blocking" }

Comment: Check your return values from your query; you can also `var_dump($row)` to see what's in there.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of your SQL statement? It is just repeating the same text string for every row in the DUAL table.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code was from copied from php.net. There really isn't much of a difference, I just put my information in the $c variable, mysql_select_db function and my query in the $result variable.    $c = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "f2f3243f2");
mysql_select_db("my_DB"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fakeDB");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);

Comment: andrewsi, this var_dump function gave the results I wanted! Thank you! array(5) { ["CharName"]=> string(6) "Majaba" ["Level"]=> string(1) "3" ["class"]=> string(4) "Bard" ["race"]=> string(8) "High Elf" ["skills"]=> string(8) "Blocking" }

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_extension! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Yeah I don't use that method anymore anyway. Because I'm using Wordpress, I've changed all my code to use the $wpdb (Wordpress database) class.

Answer (score 0):

@andrewsi wrote in a comment:

> Check your return values from your query; you can also `var_dump($row)` to see what's in there.

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat))

Answer (score -1):

```
$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM    DUAL");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['_message'];
}
```

Comment: How will adding a while loop help solve the problem?